# CefSharp does not save cookies/cache creating new RequestContext()

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I try this:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
settings.CachePath = path;

Cef.Initialize(settings);

browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://gmail.com", new RequestContext());
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Controls.Add(browser);
```

It looks like it saves because files appear inside the folder, but when I log in again I logout any site

Removing the context request it saves, but I need it

Comment: You haven't set a cache path for the RequestContext.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried the RainMaster solution : it works for me.

Just with a

`Cef.Shutdown();`

in the Form_closing, the cache is saved in the userFolder.